# How to fix npm shrinkwrap not working in locking down dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, shrinkwrap, npm-shrinkwrap

This is the scenario:

I have a package, say `package-a` that depends on `package-b`. I have version `2.0.0` of `package-a` depends on version `1.1.0` of `package-b`. I specified this dependency using the notation: `^1.1.0`. I generated the lock file and then the shrinkwrap. I then publish `package-a` to the repository.

My understanding is that the above ensures that whenever version `2.0.0` of `package-a` is installed it will always use version `1.1.0` of `package-b` even if there are newer version of `package-b`.

This does not seem to be the case, because when I bumb `package-b` to `1.2.0`, then I deleted `package-a` and re-installed it, when I check its node_module, I see it installs version `1.2.0` of `package-b` with it (instead of `1.1.0` that is specified in the shrinkwrap file)

How to I fix this? How do I ensure that my package will always install what is found in the shrinkwrap file?

Or maybe I understand how the nom shrinkwrap file should work? If so an explanation of why what I did, did not work. I would appreciate pointers on how to also make it work as I want